# ¿Cómo insertar datos en tablas relacionadas con laravel/lumen?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, relaciones, lumen

Estoy realizando una **Api de Tareas con autenticación**. Lo que quiero lograr es que, para que un usuario pueda crear una tarea, **debe estar logueado**. Además, también, **cada usuario verá sólo, sus tareas**.

Ya realice las relaciones con las `migraciones y con eloquent`. La relación es de `1:n`. Es decir, **un usuario, puede tener muchas tareas. Y, una sola tarea, depende de un usuario**. Teniendo esto presente, realicé las migraciones de la siguiente manera:

1. Migración de Usuarios:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('name', 20);
            $table->string('last_name', 20);
            $table->string('username', 20);
            $table->string('pass');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

2. Migración de Task

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateTasksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('title', 40);
            $table->string('body');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unique();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tasks');
    }
}
```

Ahora, los modelos

1. User

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
// use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;


class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'last_name', 'username', 'pass'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'pass',
    ];


     // Relación 1:n
    public function task()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Task');
    }
}
```

2. Task

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'body'
    ];

    // Relación 1:n (inversa)
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

Cuando intento hacer el registro, `desde postman`, me dice que el `campo user_id` no existe en la tabla task.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en la base de datos, si aparece en el campo en la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera intento hacer el registro:

```
{
   "title": "Hola",
   "body": "Mundo",
   "user_id": 1
}
```

`Proceso de Registro`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Task;
use App\Services\Implementation\TaskServiceImplement;

use App\Validation\TaskValidator;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    private $request;


    /**
     * @var TaskServiceImplement
     */
    private $taskServiceImplement;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $validator;

    public function __construct(Request $request, TaskServiceImplement $taskServiceImplement,
        TaskValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->request              = $request;
        $this->taskServiceImplement = $taskServiceImplement;
        $this->validator            = $validator;
    }


    /** Obtner todas las tareas **/
    public function listTask()
    {
        return response($this->taskServiceImplement->getTask());
    }


    /** Crear Tareas **/

    public function createdTask ()
    {

        $this->validate($this->request, [
            "title" => "required",
            "body" => "required",
            "user_id" => "required"
        ]);

        $this->taskServiceImplement->postTask($this->request->all());

        return response('Task Saved', 201);
    }
}
```

De ante mano, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Muestranos como intentas hacer dicho registro

Comment: Lo que te dice es que `user_id` no tiene un valor por defecto, y no que la columna no existe. Tendrías que mostrar la consulta que haces a BD para insertar el registro. Otra cosa, si la relación es 1:n, o como la defines en el modelo `hasMany`, en la migración no deberías poner `unique` en `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unique();`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ  Listo amigo, ya lo edite y agregué el proceso de registro.

Comment: Ok, pero `$this->taskServiceImplement->postTask($this->request->all());` no dice mucho, solamente llamas a una función de otra clase....  En principio, ¿que te devuelve un dump de `$this->request->all()`? Y luego, ¿que hay en la función `postTask` de la clase `TaskServiceImplement`?

Comment: esta es la function: `function postTask(array $task) { $this->model->create($task);  }`

Comment: Si usas el método `create` tienes que asegurate de que la propiedad `user_id` esté incluída en el array $fillable de tu modelo.

Comment: jajajajaj si... era eso. Muchas gracias